# how can i catch the error with errorgroup?

Tags: go

here I want the "run" function in the runner.go package to run continuously by using the "errorgroup". How can I catch this error later when it receives an error? Below is a sample code block that I want to do but fail.

Thank you.

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "awesomeProject/runner"
    "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    ctx := context.Background()
    g, ctx := errgroup.WithContext(ctx)

    g.Go(func() (err error) {
        return runner.Start(ctx, 1 * time.Second)
    })

    if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println("app terminated")
    }
}
```

runner.go

```
package runner

import (
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func Start(ctx context.Context, dur time.Duration) error {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(dur)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return nil
        case <-ticker.C:
            run(ctx)

        }
    }
}

func run(ctx context.Context) error {

    fmt.Println(time.Now().String())
    return errors.New("run:error")
}
```

Comment: Return the error from Start? `if err := run(ctx); err != nil { return err }`

Comment: In this application, the function did not check the returned value with error in the code block on line 73.

https://github.com/drone/drone/blob/0c087df4305a640401a4d1d2f3386d6a86c3643c/metric/sink/datadog.go#L68

Comment: If you want to handle the error, then that's not the application code to copy.  The code at line 73 ignores the error returned from `d.do()`.

Comment: but the Start function returns an error?